Django ListView not displaying data from database despite model being populated
I'm new to Django and trying to create a simple blog application. I have a ListView that should display all blog posts from my database, but the template is showing an empty page. I've confirmed that there are entries in the database through the admin panel.
Here's my code:
# models.py
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import BlogPost

class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/blog_list.html'

# blog_list.html template
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in blogpost_list %}
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
I checked the database through admin panel and confirmed posts exist
Tried printing queryset in the view using print(self.get_queryset())
Changed template variable from blogpost_list to object_list
A wanted list of all blog posts displayed on the page, but instead, I'm getting a blank page with no errors.

blogpost_list -> object_list

{% for post in blogpost_list %} How do you expect the template to know what blogpost_list is?  That's obviously a variable name you just made up yourself.

I don't know why nobody has been pointing you to the Django documentation, but here it is. Basically what both willeM_Van Onset and John Gordon have been pointing to. The context that is passed to the template has your query_set (BlogPost.objects.all()) assigned to the default variable object_list. You can change it to blogpost_list by overriding the default variable by assigning context_object_name  to blogpost_list  on the BlogListView class

In views.py , add this code, passes the queryset as 'blogpost_list' to the template
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import BlogPost
class BlogListView(ListView):
model = BlogPost
template_name = 'blog/blog_list.html'
context_object_name = 'blogpost_list' 

